# Scala multi-partition a map - type mismatch; Found (A,B) => Boolean required (A,B) => Boolean?

Tags: scala, types, dictionary, data-partitioning

I'm trying to multi-partition a map based on a list of predicates.

I wrote the following function to do that:

```
def multipartition[A,B](map : Map[A,B], list : List[(A,B) => Boolean]) : List[Map[A,B]] = 
    list match {
        case Nil => 
            Nil
        case l :: ls => 
            val (a, b) = map partition l; // type mismatch; found (A,B) => Boolean, required: (A,B) => Boolean
            return a :: multipartition(b, ls)
}
```

The scala compiler (I'm running 2.9.1) fails at the indicated place with a "type mismatch; found (A,B) => Boolean, required: (A,B) => Boolean".

Has anyone ever seen anything like that? Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks,

LP

Answer (score 11):

partition expects `Function[(A,B), Boolean]`, that is a function of **one** pair argument, not a function of two arguments (rather annoying that they are different)

So you need to write `((A,B)) => Boolean` as the type of elements of your list

(The error message is not helpful at all, close to a minor bug)

Comment: Don't know about 2.9.1, but on 2.9.0-1 the REPL gives the error message `found   : (A, B) => Boolean  required: ((A, B)) => Boolean` so that seems fine

Comment: I had no way to test immediately. Hope there was no regression. Could it be that the REPL gives better messages than the compiler?

Comment: @didierd It seems there was a regression indeed. I opened [SI-5007](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5007) about it.

Answer (score 7):

Complementing [didierd's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754787/didierd) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469815/scala-multi-partition-a-map-type-mismatch-found-a-b-boolean-required-a-b/7469967#7469967), you can solve it by writing it like this:

```
        val (a, b) = map partition l.tupled;
```